# How can I use vim plugins with Ideavim?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, vim-plugin, ideavim

I would like to use Tim Pope's vim [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) in my Pycharm IDE. I've been using the IdeaVim plugin for Pycharm to use vim motions and commands.

I know I can use `~/.ideavimrc` like my normal `.vimrc` but I cannot find 
information about how to use plugins with ideavim.

Can I specify the plugins directory inside my `~/.ideavimrc` or do I have to go another way? Can I use a plugin manager like pathogen?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The latest version of IdeaVim includes the vim-surround plugin. Enable it by adding

`set surround`

to your `.ideavimrc` file

https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#emulated-vim-plugins

Comment: Looks like all of us came here looking for a way to add `Vim Surround` only.

Comment: You probably also want `set commentary` from the same plugin author, which comments out the current line when you hit `gcc`

Answer (score 8):

Most applications only emulate Vim's / vi key bindings (and often only the basic navigation and editing commands). That goes a long way to helping vi users edit comfortably, but it isn't the real thing.

Unfortunately, to be able to use Vim plugins, you'll need the full Vimscript interpreter and infrastructure around `'runtimepath'`. I'm not aware of *any* application that provides this, and because of the complexities and idiosyncrasies of Vim, this would be very hard indeed.

To get more of Vim's special capabilities into your IDE, use *both* concurrently; it is very easy to set up a external tool in your IDE that launches Vim with the current file (and position). Automatic reloading of changes allows you to edit source code in both concurrently.

<sup>If it's any comfort to you, the same applies to Emacs / Elisp as well.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

The [ideaVim plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164?pr=idea) added "Support for vim-surround commands `ys`, `cs`, `ds`, `S`, enable it with `set surround` in your ~/.ideavimrc" since version 0.46.

Answer (score 6):

No. Vote for [VIM-506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-506) for Vim scripts support (unlikely to be implemented) and for [VIM-769](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-769) for vim-surround emulation (likely to appear in future versions).

Answer (score 1):

This was mentioned in a changelog relatively recently.
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/CHANGES.md#features-5
I didn't mange this work. Looks like I need `vim-plug` installed and I use another package manager in my NeoVim and also I don't want to mix up two configs. It should work in general.